# Is $\vec{r}(t)=(a\cos(ωt),a\sin(ωt), bt)$ a curve parametrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

We want to show that the vector map
$$\vec{r}:\Bbb{R}\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^3,\ \vec{r}(t)=(a\cos(ωt),a\sin(ωt), bt)$$ is a curve parametrization, if $a,ω,b >0$.

- We will show at first that $\vec{r} \in C^1$ . The 1st order derivative is $\vec{r'}(t)=(-aω\sin(ωt),aω\cos(ωt),b)$, and all it's components maps are continuous in $\Bbb{R}$. So, $\vec{r}\in C^1$.
- $||\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}||=\sqrt{a^2ω^2+b^2}>0 \implies \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \neq \vec{0}$.
- Now, we would like to show that the function $\vec{f}:\Bbb{R}\longrightarrow\vec{r}(\Bbb{R}),\ t\mapsto \vec{f}(t)=(a\cos(ωt),a\sin(ωt), bt)$ is bijection.
  For all $t,s\in \Bbb{R}: \vec{f}(t)=\vec{f}(s)\iff (a\cos(ωt),a\sin(ωt), bt)=(a\cos(ωs),a\sin(ωs), bs) \iff a\cos(ωt)=a\cos(ωs), a\sin(ωt)= a\sin(ωs),bt = bs \implies t=s$.

Is this proof completely right?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Everything you have proven here is certainly correct (although I don't know why you require $f:\mathbb{R}\to\vec{r}(\mathbb{R})$ to be a bijection).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The 3rd point, is because we dont want our curve to intersect itself. Is this false?

Comment: Well if you don't want a self-intersecting curve, and if that's how curves were defined in your context, then you should absolutely prove that that map is injective. But I consider self-intersecting curves to be, well, also curves.

Comment: The truth is that there is a confusion around this definition, but unfortunately this definition was given in my course notes... So, I have to proove the 3rd step.